# How to use "git bisect run" for locating first commit introducing a string into a file which only exists in some commits

Tags: git, matching, bisect

Let's say I want to locate the first (oldest) Git revision which adds the line `delta` to text file `file`.

But I want to use `git bisect` for this rather than searching the output of `git log -p` because of performance reasons (huge repository).

First create a repository `testrepo` as a test case for demonstrating the search:

```
r=testrepo
git init $r && cd $r
dt='2022-12-07 11:30:00 +0100'
an='Guenther Brunthaler' ae='some_username@somewhere.example'
for add in alpha beta gamma delta epsilon zeta eta
do
    echo $add >> file
    git add file
    GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$an" GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$an" \
        GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$ae" GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$ae" \
        GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="$dt" GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$dt" \
        git commit -m "Adding $add"
done
unset r dt am ae
```

This repository contains a file `file` to which the next Greek letter name has been appended in every revision.

Now we want to locate the commit which added the line `delta`.

This should be commit `a2444b7`, because:

```
$ git log --oneline | grep delta | tail -n 1
a2444b7 Adding delta
```

### Does not work yet

Use the "git bisect" command like this:

```
relfile=file added=delta
initial=`git log --graph --pretty=%h | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | tail -n 1`

git bisect reset # optional: abort an already running bisect

git bisect start
git bisect bad HEAD
git bisect good $initial
git bisect run sh -c "test ! -e '${relfile?:}' || grep -qv '${added?:}' '${relfile?:}'"
```

where `$initial` is the commit ID of the initial commit, `$added` is the RegEx for locating the new feature within file `$relfile`.

The above command should display the ID of the commit introducing the feature:

```
b0ece99babe9ffb16b7792d4e810cb3cc9571385 is the first bad commit
```

But obviously, this is the wrong commit!

What can I do in order to make `git bisect run` report revision `a2444b7` as the `first bad commit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The success exit status of `grep` tells that any lines would be printed printed. Usually, this coincides with whether a line that matches the pattern was found. But when you pass `-v`, successful exit happens when at least one non-matching line was found. That is not what you want.

Use `! grep` without `-v` to stop at the correct commit:

```
git bisect run sh -c "test ! -e '${relfile?:}' || ! grep -q '${added?:}' '${relfile?:}'"
```

Comment: I am such an id***! Thanks! The solution can even be further simplified to >>>git bisect run sh -c "! grep -sq '${added?:}' '${relfile?:}'"<<<.